# How can I install "Ubuntu minimal install" packages that are not installed with it?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, minimal-install

I Installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS selecting the minimal install option. But I wanted a full install. I read that minimal install removes around 80 packages. Is there any way in which I can install just these things again without a full install again?

Comment: It is possible to install additional software. Are you asking which packages were omitted, or how to install packages that you already know you want?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, I want to know which packages were omitted and also how to install them? Can I install all of them at once?

Comment: It should be possible. I will look for a list.

Comment: I think if you install ubuntu-desktop you will get all that was left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of the packages omitted when doing a minimal install can be found here: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove

You may not want all this stuff - you can pick and choose.

You can open a terminal and use the command `sudo apt install XXXX` where XXXX is the package name.

It is possible to supply a long list of packages to install at once - separate them by spaces.